# django form "unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'"

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm probably doing something obviously wrong here like missing an import.

```
from django import forms  
from swap_meet.inventory.models import Item 

class AddOrderForm(forms.Form):
    test = forms.ChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.all())
```

Error I get is `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ChoiceFields don't take a queryset argument. You're looking for [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

Answer (score 4):

`queryset` is an argument for [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield). For `ChoiceField` you want [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield)

Answer (score 2):

For ChoiceField you can use

```
    test = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[
    (item.pk, item) for item in Item.objects.all()])
```

In general choices are a list of tuples

Comment: Using Python 3.6+, Django 3.1.6: `test = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[(item.pk, item) for item in YourModel.objects.all()])` now is possible